# Error when inputting array of outside data into TensorFlow model.predict()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

We successfully trained a TensorFlow model based on five climate features and one binary (0 or 1) label. We want an output for an outside input of five new climate variable values that will be inputted into model.predict(). However, we got an error when we tried to input an array of five values. Thanks in advance!

```
def split_dataset(dataset, test_ratio=0.10):
  """Splits a panda dataframe in two."""
  test_indices = np.random.rand(len(dataset)) < test_ratio
  return dataset[~test_indices], dataset[test_indices]


train_ds_pd, test_ds_pd = split_dataset(dataset_df)
print("{} examples in training, {} examples for testing.".format(
    len(train_ds_pd), len(test_ds_pd)))
label = "Presence"
train_ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(train_ds_pd, label=label)
test_ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(test_ds_pd, label=label)

model_1 = tfdf.keras.RandomForestModel()

model_1.compile(
    metrics=["accuracy"])


with sys_pipes():
  model_1.fit(x=train_ds)
evaluation = model_1.evaluate(test_ds, return_dict=True)
print()

for name, value in evaluation.items():
  print(f"{name}: {value:.4f}")
model_1.save("tfmodelmosquito")
import numpy as np
model_1=tf.keras.models.load_model ("tfmodelmosquito")
import pandas as pd

prediction = model_1.predict([9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0])
print (prediction)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-be5f2b7bc739> in <module>()
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 
----> 5 prediction = model.predict([[9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0]])
      6 print (prediction)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1569 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1559 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1552 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1525 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py:69 return_outputs_and_add_losses
        outputs, losses = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py:167 wrap_with_training_arg
        lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py:110 smart_cond
        pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py:56 smart_cond
        return false_fn()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py:167 <lambda>
        lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py:163 replace_training_and_call
        return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:889 __call__
        result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:933 _call
        self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:764 _initialize
        *args, **kwds))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:3050 _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
        graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:3444 _maybe_define_function
        graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:3289 _create_graph_function
        capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:999 func_graph_from_py_func
        func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:672 wrapped_fn
        out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/function_deserialization.py:291 restored_function_body
        "\n\n".join(signature_descriptions)))

    ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (2 total):
        * Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None, 5), dtype=float32)
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
    
    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (2 total):
        * {'Humidity': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Humidity'), 'Cloud_Cover': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Cloud_Cover'), 'Temperature': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Temperature'), 'Pressure': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Pressure'), 'Precipitation': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Precipitation')}
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (2 total):
        * {'Temperature': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Temperature'), 'Precipitation': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Precipitation'), 'Cloud_Cover': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Cloud_Cover'), 'Humidity': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Humidity'), 'Pressure': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs/Pressure')}
        * True
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (2 total):
        * {'Cloud_Cover': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Cloud_Cover'), 'Humidity': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Humidity'), 'Precipitation': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Precipitation'), 'Temperature': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Temperature'), 'Pressure': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Pressure')}
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}
    
    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (2 total):
        * {'Temperature': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Temperature'), 'Precipitation': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Precipitation'), 'Humidity': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Humidity'), 'Cloud_Cover': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Cloud_Cover'), 'Pressure': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Pressure')}
        * True
      Keyword arguments: {}
```

Comment: In your code above, there is no line that saves the model, so this is not a minimal working example, and thus the variable `model` wouldn't point to anything, but `model_1` would. Can you please include the line (and output if possible) to where you've saved your model? It should be something like this: `model_1.save("tfmodelmosquito")`

Comment: @TCArlen Sorry about that, please see my edits in the code. I mistyped my question but I still have the same error with everything named as model_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a be a sample array input. Convert it to a pandas dataframe and then a TF dataset. This worked for me.

```
a = [17, 88, 1000, 0.47, 95]
df=pd.DataFrame (columns=["Temperature", "Humidity", "Pressure", "Precipitation", "Cloud Cover"])
df.loc[len(df)] = a
df_ds=tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(df)

model_1=tf.keras.models.load_model("tfmodelmosquito")

prediction = model_1.predict(df_ds)
print (prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict), in Keras, model.predict() expects a numpy array. So try this:

```py
import numpy as np
prediction = model.predict(np.array([9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0]))
```

Comment: I tried this and get the same error with the code from the question.

Comment: Can you list the versions of the relevant packages so I can try to help more? `tensorflow`, `numpy`, `python`.

Comment: TensorFlow: 2.5.0, Numpy: 1.19.5, Python:  3.8.5